# Detect stopping of Telegram bot

Tags: telegram, chatbot, telegram-bot

Does Telegram bot receive any message when the user stops the bot?

When the user starts communication with a bot, he/she sends "/start" command/message to the bot. I would like to know when the user decided to leave.

Comment: Found a close question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35263618/how-can-i-detect-whether-a-user-deletes-the-telegram-bot-chat, so probably the answer is No, if Telegram didn't update it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `InlineKeyboardMarkup` I would suggest to use timeout parameter in `MessageLoop`, so you would know when the user stops sending callback queries.

Something like this

> `ERROR:root:on_close() called due to IdleTerminate: 1   #1 sec termination`

Otherwise there is no method to know that the user has stopped interacting with the bot.